# Updating Angular Local Library Project

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-upgrade

I've an Angular project in 7.1. I have also created 2 angular libraries which are used in my project. I'm upgrading my project from 7.1 to 8.2. I ran the following command for the upgrade which upgraded my angular project.

```
ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
```

But it didn't upgrade my library project. How can I upgrade the angular version in my library project? I can manually update the package version in package.json in my library project but then I would need to do all the changes (eg, adding static for viewChild) manually.

Looking forward to some expert advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a duplicate of [How to update an Angular library project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68373297/how-to-update-an-angular-library-project) . See my answer there as well. According to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14472#issuecomment-605411866), it's intentional that peerDependencies of a library's package.json should be updated manually.