# How to update an Angular library project?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular library which is generated using Angular 11 version. Now I want to update it to Angular 12 but no luck using ng update command.
I have used the below command.

```
ng update --project my-lib
```

The above library is published in npm. Now I want to update it to the latest version.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a nice way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately no @S.tenBrinke

Comment: What about now mate ? I'm trying to find this solution too

Comment: @RaphaëlEtang-Salé not yet..

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14472#issuecomment-605411866), you need to update the peerDependencies of your library yourself, so according to that info, I think it's normal that `ng update` doesn't update the library's package.json.

Answer (score 1):

change version in dist/package.json
run command ng version 0.0.2
run command